# PGF/TikZ: How to store strings in array?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, arrays

I'm trying to generate a lot of name badges. I'm wondering, is it possible to store the names as strings in one array, according to the PGF manual:

```
\def\myarray{{1,"two",2+1,"IV","cinq","sechs",sin(\i*5)*14}}
```

I tried this:

```
\def\names{{"Katie","Frank","Laura","Joe"}}
```

Without success, because it seems to store the whole string in `\names` variable, and if I write

```
\names[2]
```

The output will be

```
"Katie","Frank","Laura","Joe"
```

instead

```
Laura
```

is what I want to write out.

So why is this not working? How could I use arrays? Does it require some special library?

Comment: Is this for using in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Here is an example that does not require quotes: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mylist{Laura,Katie,Frank,Joe}
\foreach[count=\xi] \x in \mylist \node[minimum width=1cm] (n\xi) at (\xi,\xi) {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}`. The quotes are needed when you plugin your list into a macro and to protect the text from a math parser!

Comment: No, i use it not in a foreach loop. Without foreach loop somehow it doesn't work for me, it gives back the whole string. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This answer may be more generic than specifically relating to TikZ/PGF.

(La)TeX is a macro-based language, so it does not work as expected compared to other languages when dealing with "arrays". For example, while `\names[2]` should yield `Laura` where

```
\def\names{Katie, Frank, Laura, Joe}
```

(indexing from 0), (La)TeX considers `[2]` to have no connection to `\names`. As such, you're more likely to obtain the output `Katie, Frank, Laura, Joe[2]` - a concatenation of `\names` (as it is defined) and `[2]`.

In order to allow for indexing like one typically would using arrays, you would need some other functionality. Here's an example of a list parser that works like you would expect arrays do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcounter{listtotal}\newcounter{listcntr}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\names}{o}{%
  \setcounter{listtotal}{0}\setcounter{listcntr}{-1}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listtotal}}%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\namesarray}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\namesarray}% \names
    {% \names[<index>]
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listcntr}\ifnum\value{listcntr}=#1\relax##1\fi}%
     \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\namesarray}}%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\namesarray}{Katie, Frank, Laura, Joe}%
\verb|\names:|\ \names \par
\verb|\names[2]:|\ \names[2] \par
\verb|\names[0]:|\ \names[0] \par
\verb|\names[5]:|\ \names[5]
\end{document}
```

The idea here is to store the names in an array `\namesarray` and then define a *macro* (or "function") that takes an *optional argument*. If no argument is supplied (i.e., you just use `\names`), then you print the entire `\namesarray`. If an argument is supplied (of the form `\names[<index>]`), parse the list sequentially to find that item that matches `<index>` and print it.

The list parser relies on [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\docsvlist` and enumerator `\do`.

Comment: Wow, you implemented it very professionally! It works fine. I'm just adding one comment: i can get the values of the array with a counter, like this:

    \newcounter{i}
    \setcounter{i}{0}
    \names[\value{i}]
    \stepcounter{i}

...So it's perfect!

Comment: Is it possible to get the size of the array? (I would like to use it in a \forloop)

Comment: @Zach: You can use `\sbox9=\hbox{\names}` (processes `\names` but doesn't print it) which then allows you to use the `listtotal` counter that holds the number of items in the list.

Answer (score 43):

To answer the specific question you are asking, here is a complete minimal example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\begin{document}
\def\names{{"Katie","Frank","Laura","Joe"}}%
\pgfmathparse{\names[2]}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

So, you need to use the `pgfmath` parser to do the job through `\pgfmathparse` and then use the result of the parsing with `\pgfmathresult`: in other words, you cannot call `\names[2]` directly.

Here is a more complete example with a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\names{{"Katie","Frank","Laura","Joe"}}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {%
  Name \i: \pgfmathparse{\names[\i]}\pgfmathresult, }
\end{document}
```

Comment: So now it's clear for me, what i need to make it work like in the PGF manual. Thanks!

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't work for me. Gives an error:  `Undefined control sequence. \pgfkeys`. After replacing `\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}` to `\usepackage{tikz}` it worked.

Comment: Where is this syntax documented? I searched the documentation and found nothing...

Answer (score 14):

The `arrayjob` package has some more macros for using the data array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob}

\newarray\names
\readarray{names}{Katie&Frank&Laura&Joe}

\begin{document}
\verb|\names(3):|\ \names(3) \par
\verb|\names(1):|\ \names(1) \par
\verb|\names(5):|\ \names(5)
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
The arrays are 1 based (index starts at `1`)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need arrays (but arrays are described in the `pgf` manual). Also you don't need numbers to "index" the arrays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \pgfkeys{/English to German/Peter/.code=Peter,
            /English to German/Mary/.code=Maria,
            /German to English/Peter/.code=Peter,
            /German to English/Maria/.code=Mary}

\pgfkeys{/English to German/Peter}, % -> Peter
\pgfkeys{/English to German/Mary}, % -> Maria
\pgfkeys{/German to English/Peter}, and % -> Peter, and
\pgfkeys{/German to English/Maria}. % -> Mary.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's easy, and works good. If i understand good, with this solution, i can define only one list?

Comment: No, you can have several lists. I've changed my example to show this.

Comment: @user10247: please insert \begin{document} into your code.