# Creating macros for common commutative diagrams in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am currently typesetting a document which requires many commutative diagrams of the same shape and construction, but with different labels at the vertices and edges. For example, I want a commutative diagram which describes the associative structure of an algebra. This I can do with:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,
row sep=2.6em, column sep=2.8em,
text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex]
{(A\otimes A)\otimes A& & A\otimes (A\otimes A)\\
A\otimes A& &A\otimes A\\
 &A& \\};
\path[->,font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$\mu\otimes Id$} (m-2-1)
(m-2-1) edge node[auto] {$\mu$} (m-3-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[auto] {$ Id\otimes\mu$} (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge node[auto] {$ \mu$} (m-3-2);
\path[<->, font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$\alpha$} (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

In the same section, I also want to use a commutative diagram to express the monoidal structure of a group. In my document as it stands, this is exactly the same code, but with different labels. As I go forward, I know that this is a diagram which I will likely use very often, and would like to not have to copy and paste this exact code into each new document.

I naively tried using `\newcommand{\monoid}[8]{...}` to wrap the whole thing, however this did not work. Is there a way to define a macro around this environment so that I can specify only the arguments I need and not be cluttered by having to copy and paste the whole block every time?

Comment: Please explain what "didn't work". `\newcommand` is pretty much what you should use, so please give us your faulty code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to replace the ampersands in the TikZ matrix using the key `ampersand replacement=<macro>`, where `<macro>` can be `\&`, for example.

Here's your code as a command. I used the approach described in [PGF/TikZ: How to store strings in array?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/pgf-tikz-how-to-store-strings-in-array/45043#45043) for using a list instead of separate arguments for the labels. Your diagram

[image]

can then be created using

```
\monoid{
    (A\otimes A)\otimes A,
    A\otimes (A\otimes A),
    A\otimes A,
    A\otimes A,
    A,
    $\mu\otimes Id$,
    $\mu$,
    $ Id\otimes\mu$,
    $ \mu$,
    $\alpha$
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{listtotal}\newcounter{listcntr}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\argument}{o}{%
  \setcounter{listtotal}{0}\setcounter{listcntr}{-1}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listtotal}}%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\argumentarray}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\namesarray}% \names
    {% \names[<index>]
     \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\stepcounter{listcntr}\ifnum\value{listcntr}=#1\relax##1\fi}%
     \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\argumentarray}}%
}

\newcommand{\monoid}[1]{
\def\argumentarray{#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix(m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        ampersand replacement=\&,
        row sep=2.6em,
        column sep=2.8em,
        text height=2ex,
        text depth=0.5ex
    ]
    {
    \argument[0]    \&              \& \argument[1]\\
    \argument[2]    \&              \& \argument[3]\\
                    \& \argument[4] \& \\
    };
\path[->,font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[5]} (m-2-1)
(m-2-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[6]} (m-3-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[auto] {\argument[8]} (m-2-3)
(m-2-3) edge node[auto] {\argument[9]} (m-3-2);
\path[<->, font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[10]} (m-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\monoid{
    (A\otimes A)\otimes A,
    A\otimes (A\otimes A),
    A\otimes A,
    A\otimes A,
    A,
    $\mu\otimes Id$,
    $\mu$,
    $ Id\otimes\mu$,
    $ \mu$,
    $\alpha$
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

- Use `tikz-cd` for simple contruction of commutative diagrams
- Use the `arrayjobx` package for the elements

Benefits:

- Shorter diagram code, arrows directly within the elements
- Instead of writing 9 parameters each time you call `\monoid`, you could modify just specific array arguments if diagrams are similar, such as by `\monoidelements(1)={A'\otimes A'}` and calling `\monoid` again

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newarray{monoidelements}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\monoid}[1]{
  \begin{tikzcd}[->,font=\normalsize,>=angle 90,ampersand replacement=\&]
  #1(1) \arrow{d}{#1(6)} \arrow[<->]{rr}{\alpha}\& \& #1(2) \arrow{d}{#1(7)}\\
  #1(3) \arrow{dr}{#1(8)} \& \& #1(4)\arrow{dl}{#1(9)}\\
   \& #1(5) \&
  \end{tikzcd}}

\begin{document}
\readarray{monoidelements}{(A\otimes A)\otimes A\otimes A&A\otimes (A\otimes A)
  &A\otimes A&A\otimes A&A&\mu\otimes Id&Id\otimes\mu&\mu&\mu\otimes Id}
\monoid{\monoidelements}
\end{document}
```

[image: Monoid]

Answer (score 5):

An answer which is too long for being a comment, as it's only a rewriting of Jake's answer using a shorter syntax based on `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_jake_monoid_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\monoid}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jake_monoid_seq { , } { #1 }
  \domonoid
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\argument}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { \seq_use:N \l_jake_monoid_seq }
   { \seq_item:Nn \l_jake_monoid_seq { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand{\domonoid}{}
 {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix(m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        ampersand replacement=\&,
        row sep=2.6em,
        column sep=2.8em,
        text height=2ex,
        text depth=0.5ex
    ]
    {
    \argument[0]    \&              \& \argument[1]\\
    \argument[2]    \&              \& \argument[3]\\
                    \& \argument[4] \& \\
    };
  \path[->,font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
  (m-1-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[5]} (m-2-1)
  (m-2-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[6]} (m-3-2)
  (m-1-3) edge node[auto] {\argument[8]} (m-2-3)
  (m-2-3) edge node[auto] {\argument[9]} (m-3-2);
  \path[<->, font=\normalsize,>=angle 90]
  (m-1-1) edge node[auto] {\argument[10]} (m-1-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
 }
\begin{document}
\monoid{
    (A\otimes A)\otimes A,
    A\otimes (A\otimes A),
    A\otimes A,
    A\otimes A,
    A,
    $\mu\otimes \mathit{Id}$,
    $\mu$,
    $ \mathit{Id}\otimes\mu$,
    $ \mu$,
    $\alpha$
}

\end{document}
```

The `\monoid` macro does two things: it sets a sequence from its argument and calls `\domonoid` which is identical to Jake's `\monoid`. Notice that `\domonoid` *must* be defined with `\ExplSyntaxOff`, because spaces in TikZ keys are significant.

The definition of `\argument` is *much* easier than with `etoolbox`.

Note: in order to get a better form of *Id*, it's better to use `\mathit{Id}`.

---

We can use similar ideas also for Stefan Kottwitz's answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\NewDocumentCommand{\monoid}{m}
 {
  \makeargument{#1}    
  \begin{tikzcd}[->,font=\normalsize,>=angle 90,ampersand replacement=\&]
  \argument{0} \arrow{d}{\argument{5}} \arrow[<->]{rr}{\alpha}\& \& \argument{1} \arrow{d}{\argument{6}}\\
  \argument{2} \arrow{dr}{\argument{7}} \& \& \argument{3}\arrow{dl}{\argument{8}}\\
   \& \argument{4} \&
  \end{tikzcd}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_sk_monoid_seq
\cs_new:Npn \makeargument #1
 { \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_sk_monoid_seq { & } { #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \argument #1
 { \seq_item:Nn \l_sk_monoid_seq {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\monoid{
  (A\otimes A)\otimes A\otimes A &
  A\otimes (A\otimes A) &
  A\otimes A &
  A\otimes A &
  A &
  \mu\otimes\mathit{Id} &
  \mathit{Id}\otimes\mu &
  \mu &
  \mu\otimes\mathit{Id}
}
\end{document}
```