# Tikzmath: use array

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I'd like to use arrays in `tikzmath`. I'd like to be able to manually define an array, with the equivalent of the python code `myarray = [1,0,0,1,1]`, and I also would like to be able to access it in tikzmath, using something like `myarray[3]` as well as modify it, using something like `myarray[4] = 42`. I found two ways to deal with arrays, but each method has a problem.

The first one (see my MWE) is interesting because it lets me define arrays on the fly, but I don't know how to manually initialize this array using one line, without using a loop to compute the value.

The second solution I found has the opposite problem: I can define an array in a one-line manner, but then access it in `tikzmath` is difficult, and I need to use crazy structures like:

```
\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\s]}
\edef\val{\pgfmathresult}
```

While I'd like to use directly `\myarray[\s]` in the `tikzmath` code.

Do you know what is the best way to create an array that you can easily access and modify in `tikzmath`, and such that if needed I can specify the initial value in a single line command?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}    

%%% FIRST METHOD
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \n = 5;
    % Works, but one problem: how to manually choose the values
    % without using a loop?
    int \i;
    for \i in {1,...,\n}{
      \myarray{\i} = mod(\i,2);
    };
    % Display
    for \i in {1,...,\n}{
      if \myarray{\i} == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30";}
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30"; };
      {\node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\i-1)}:2cm) {$\i$};};
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

%%% SECOND METHOD
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{5}
  \def\myarray{{42,1,0,1,1,0}}
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
    %%% Works but not really easy to read/write, and is not inside the
    %%% tikzmath code.
    % \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\s]}
    % \edef\val{\pgfmathresult}
    % \tikzmath{ if \val == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30"; }
    %%% Does not work, no idea why
    \tikzmath{ if \myarray[\s] == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30"; }
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30";};
    }
    \node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\s-1)}:2cm) {$\s$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that tikz arrays are constants, not variables.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?s=2|14.3981#346285 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with `listofitems`, using the simple syntax of `readlist\myarray{1,0,1,1,0}`.  This allows cell-by-cell access via the fully expandable `\myarray[5]`, for example.  One can access the fully expandable array length to set the loop limit, as I do with `\edef\n{\listlen\myarray[]}` (or, alternately, via `\edef\n{\myarraylen}`).

I have provided the `\reassignitem` macro, with syntax `\reassignitem\myarray[5]{42}`, to reassign array values.

In the MWE, subscripts have been placed on the graphical result, merely to show that the `\reassignitem` macro can, in fact, reassign the value of a list item.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\catcode`\_11
\def\reassignitem#1[#2]#3{\loi_argcsname\loi_def{\loi_macroname#1[#2]}{#3}}
\loi_restorecatcode
\begin{document}    
\readlist\myarray{1,0,1,1,0}
\reassignitem\myarray[5]{42}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % HERE CAN DEFINE \n IN TERMS OF ARRAY LENGTH, FOR EXAMPLE
  \edef\n{\listlen\myarray[]}
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
    \tikzmath{ if \myarray[\s] == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30"; }
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30";};
    }
    \node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\s-1)}:2cm) {$\s_{\myarray[\s]}$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\reassignitem` code

```
\catcode`\_11
\def\reassignitem#1[#2]#3{\loi_argcsname\loi_def{\loi_macroname#1[#2]}{#3}}
\loi_restorecatcode
```

is essentially equivalent to the following, but with `listofitems` error checking.

```
\makeatletter
\def\reassignitem#1[#2]#3{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobble\string#1[#2]\endcsname{#3}}
\makeatother
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I would be remiss if I did not provide the disclaimer that `\reassignitem` is not intended to work with nested item lists (the data in the parent/child lists will be out of sync), and that one will break `listofitems` logic if one were to reassign the separator character (here the comma`,`) as part of the reassignment replacement text.

Answer (score 7):

Accessing the array from inside `\pgfmathsetmacro`, or `\pgfmathparse`, seems to do what you want:

```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{tikz}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\n{5}
    \def\myarray{{42,1,0,1,1,0}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ccolor{ifthenelse(\myarray[\s]==1, "green!30", "blue!30")}
      \node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\s-1)}:2cm) {$\s$};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Note that you don't need `\usetikzlibrary{math}`.

The output is the same as in marmot's answer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I really would like to use the math library, I think it's really more readable and it's really easy to do computations inside.

Comment: @tobiasBora Sorry. I played with `tikzmath` a little but could not see an easier way to initialise an array

Answer (score 5):

Inside `\tikzmath` you cannot do assignments except of the allowed kind (that is, to local variables).

Here's a solution, with a reimplementation of arrays and a new keyword for `\tikzmath` that allows executing code at the same level (not in a group). Beware of not doing assignments that change the `\tikzmath` state; also no “tikzmath” is available inside it, so there must be an indirection as shown.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

% define a new keyword
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@math@process@keyword@assign{%
  \tikz@math@collecttosemicolon{\tikz@math@process@keyword@@assign}%
}
\def\tikz@math@process@keyword@@assign{%
  \tikz@math@collected\tikz@math@parse
}
\makeatother


%% Let's reimplement TikZ arrays
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \shp #1 { \prop_show:c { l_tobias_array_#1_prop } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mO{}}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = items
  \prop_clear_new:c { l_tobias_array_#1_prop }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \clist_count:n { #2 } - 1 }
   {
    \prop_put:cnx { l_tobias_array_#1_prop } { ##1 } { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 + 1 } }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setarrayitem}{mmm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = index, #3 = value
  \prop_put:cff { l_tobias_array_#1_prop } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:cf { l_tobias_array_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { cff }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cf }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}    

%%% FIRST METHOD
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \definearray{myarray}
  \tikzmath{
    \n = 5;
    % Works, but one problem: how to manually choose the values
    % without using a loop?
    int \i;
    for \i in {1,...,\n}{
      \tmp = mod(\i,2);
      assign \setarrayitem{myarray}{\i}{\tmp};
    };
    % Display
    for \i in {1,...,\n}{
      if \arrayitem{myarray}{\i} == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30";}
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30"; };
      {\node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\i-1)}:2cm) {$\i$};};
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

%%% SECOND METHOD
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{5}
  \definearray{myarray}[42,1,0,1,1,0]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  {
   \tikzmath{ if \arrayitem{myarray}{\s} == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30"; }
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30";};
    }
    \node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\s-1)}:2cm) {$\s$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Now it's a bit more like an answer. I was using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45059/121799). It is a bit odd that one needs to call `\pgfmathparse` in an tikzmath environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}    
\def\myarray{{42,1,0,2,1,0}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \n = 5;
    % Works, but one problem: how to manually choose the values
    % without using a loop?
    int \i;
    for \i in {1,...,\n}{{\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\i]}\xdef\mynum{\pgfmathresult}};
      if \mynum == 1 then { \ccolor = "green!30";}
      else { \ccolor = "blue!30"; };
      {\node[draw,circle,fill=\ccolor] at ({90+360/\n * (\i-1)}:2cm) {$\i$};};
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment. This is my (biased) opinion on using `array` in drawing with the `math` library and other programming language called Asymptote. It seems to be the difference between a graphic program and a programing language.

I have read a thread of someone (forgot the link) that said how he/she love the `math` library of TikZ because it enhances programming ability of TikZ. However I stopped using `math` library after several attempts due to its un-natural syntax. By the same reason (clean syntax), I feel comfortable with operations of `array` in Asymptote.

The below Asymptote code is self-explained, and clean I suppose.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
real r=2.5;  // radius of pentagon

// array of vertexes of the pentagon
pair[] V;    
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) 
V.push(r*dir(90+72i));

// array of filling colors
pen[] p={blue,red,purple,yellow,cyan};

// array of labels
string[] s={"$1_1$","$2_0$","$3_1$","$4_1$","$5_{42}$"};

for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
filldraw(circle(V[i],.5),p[i]+opacity(.5),black);
label(s[i],V[i]);  
}

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know asymptote, I should read about it! But the code is indeed quite clear.